# How to maximize distance in circular list for same type of objects?

Tags: algorithm, circular-list

There is N amount of arrays containing same objects. {A,A,A,A} {B,B,B,B} {C,C} {D} {E} {F}. The idea is to place them in a circular array maximizing the distance between any 2 same objects inside of it. For example in this case I expect the resulting array to be {A,B,C,F,A,B,E,A,B,C,A,B,D}. Any of single element array elements are interchangeable, and provide additional padding, since due to the circular array, distance will always be Array.Length -1

Current algorithm implementation is rather simple. I build a new 2 dimensional array with Y-axis length of longest initial array and x-axis is just the amount of arrays (infinite just to make it simple).

The new array is filled out in such manner:
{A,B,C,D}
{A,B,C,0}
{A,B,E,0}
{A,B,F,0}
0 - null
Going from top to bottom, left to right I fillout the grid placing largest amount to smallest. Then reading left to right, top to down and ignoring null values I get a semi-correct solution to the problem.
This way the solution is {A,B,C,D,A,B,C,A,B,E,A,B,F}
The only problem I'm facing is the C elements being "too close" to each other. Their current score is 3-8 instead of 5-6 or 6-5 that would be more "Just".

Another general solution was to form a mixed up array {A,B,C,D,E,F,A,B,C,A,B,A,B} then "Bubble sort" any duplicate values around, but the solution seemed to have too many edge cases. (Endless loop if any one element dominates the array)

This seems like there should be some obvious simple algorithm to maximize the distribution, but nowhere could I find such a thing. Does anyone have a solution to this problem? Is it even possible to solve it?

Edit:
Another tested solution was to equally calculate the positions where the object must be placed in. Ex. 
 {A,A,A,A} -> 0/4 1/4 2/4 3/4

 {B,B,B} -> 0/3 1/3 2/3 and so on... Also adding a little shift for every following value, just to avoid overlaps.

The problem occurs with initial Data {A,A,A,A,B,B,B,C,C,C} it is transformed into {A,B,C,A,B,C,A,B,C,A} which pushes the A value with no padding until the next object.

Edit 2: 
Adding Fitness calculation on how the list should be formed. This is more or less a brute force instead of an elegant algorithm. It does always provide the best possible solution.

The lower the value the better the result is, best possible Fitness is 0, but often that is not possible.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

float CalculateFitness(std::vector<char>& data, char tst, int count);

int main()
{
    std::vector<char> a = { 'A', 'A', 'A' };
    std::vector<char> b = { 'B', 'B' };
    std::vector<char> c = { 'C', 'C' };

    std::vector<char> data;
    data.insert(data.end(), a.begin(), a.end());
    data.insert(data.end(), b.begin(), b.end());
    data.insert(data.end(), c.begin(), c.end());

    do
    {
        for (auto val : data)
            std::cout << val;
        std::cout << ' ' << CalculateFitness(data, a[0], a.size()) + CalculateFitness(data, b[0], b.size()) + CalculateFitness(data, c[0], c.size()) << '\n';

    } while (std::next_permutation(data.begin(), data.end()));
}

float CalculateFitness(std::vector<char>& data, char tst, int count)
{
    const float mathematicallyJust = static_cast<float>(data.size()) / count;
    float result = 0;
    int lastPos = -1;
    for (auto i = 0; i <= data.size(); i++)
    {
        if (data[i % data.size()] == tst)
        {
            if (lastPos == -1)
            {
                lastPos = i;
                continue;
            }
            result += abs(mathematicallyJust - abs(lastPos - i));
            lastPos = i;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Since you're working on a circular list it's a bit odd you're not using a circle at all ... place the `A`s equispaced in angular distance (there are four of them, so 90deg apart) on the circumference of a circle, say at 0,90,180,270.  Likewise with the `B`s, nudging them a little to the clockwise, so at 1,91,181,271.  Place the Cs at 2, 182.  Treat the `D,E,F` as three instances of the same class, place at 3,123,243.  Read the order of the array from any point right round the circle.  Not sure if this is a complete solution, but it might help you along.

Comment: It's a solution, but the problem will occur with values that would overlap the circle.
Either shifting must occur or we must enter decimal calculations to expand the space to a size that none of the values would overlap. Treating the single sized ones as the same value is a nice touch, gonna test a few ideas out. Thanks. Also I don't think of it as a circle, because I find it extremely difficult to think about data inside it.